# I am uploading a file into the media folder in django using a browse button.I need to get the path of that file in my local storage

Tags: django, python-3.x, filesystems

I am trying to upload a folder using webkit directory into the media folder in django.As we can't directly copy a directory into the media folder( i think we do it in uploading a file),to do this I'm trying to make use of shutil.copytree() to copy the directory entirely into the media from my local storage and drag individual file paths and store in database.For this shutil.copytree() demands the file path as input and how do i get it from webkitdirectory.I tried it with uploading a single file....I am unable to get the file path even

## this is my form

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file"  name="myfile">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

{% if uploaded_file_url %}
  <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{uploaded_file_url }}"> 
{{uploaded_file_url 
}}</a></p>
{% endif %}

 <p><a href="{% url 'timelinemethod' %}">Return to home</a></p>
 {% endblock %}
```

## this is my view myfile is the file object after post it is displaying the path of file from media folder but i need the path in local storage as c://.... (so that in case of a folder I can copy the entire directory using shutil.copytree())

def simple_upload(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
    myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
   # f=open(myfile)
    #print("hai",f.name())
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    print(myfile)
    import shutil
   # shutil.copytree(myfile,"./media/",myfile)
    print("okay")
    print("hello",inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
    print("ok",myfile.name)
    print("not ok",myfile)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
   # print(uploaded_file_url.parts)
    print(uploaded_file_url)
    print("hello")        #import os
   # k=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(myfile))
   # print(k)
    obj= Document( document=uploaded_file_url)
    obj.save()
    return render(request, 'simple_upload.html', {
        'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
    })
return render(request, 'simple_upload.html')
```

Comment: You can't do that. Browser doesn't have access to the filesystem for security reasons.

Comment: @Borut Thanks for the clarification but how can I copy the directory into my media folder to further store all the files of the folder in database

Comment: How to copy directory from client's (local) computer? As I mentioned earlier, you cannot. User can only upload individual files, but to simplify things for the user, you can try adding `webkitdirectory multiple` to file input which allows a user to select directory, but it's a non-standard feature and won't work in all browsers. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) for example and information about this feature.